# JSON Data Export in Views Displaying Hierarchal Taxonomy Terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to create a JSON feed to be read by an external application (iOS app). I want to be able to set up a structure similar to below with views but have not been able to do so.

```
{
   "Term 1":{
        image: "http://image.com/url.jpg"
      "Term Child 1":[
         {
            "image":"2013-11-19"
         }
      ],
      "Term Child 2":[
         {
            "image":"2013-11-19"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I made a view but I do not have the option to create a contextual filter with depth. Any ideas?

Here is my view export:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'configurator_options';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Configurator Options';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'field_image' => 'field_image',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'name' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_image' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'parent';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Field: Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['id'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['field'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['label'] = 'image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['type'] = 'image_url';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['settings'] = array(
  'url_type' => '0',
  'image_style' => '',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Weight */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['weight']['id'] = 'weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['weight']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['weight']['field'] = 'weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['weight']['separator'] = '';
/* Sort criterion: Taxonomy term: Weight */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['weight_1']['id'] = 'weight_1';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['weight_1']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['weight_1']['field'] = 'weight';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['weight_1']['relationship'] = 'parent';
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy term: Vocabulary */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['vid']['id'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['vid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['vid']['field'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['vid']['value'] = array(
  1 => '1',
);

/* Display: Data export */
$handler = $view->new_display('views_data_export', 'Data export', 'views_data_export_1');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'views_data_export_json';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['provide_file'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['parent_sort'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'api/vehicles';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'temp';
```

Comment: this may be where writing your own hook menu and custom DB query and using `json_encode()` may be easier than mucking with Views. Here is a basic example I did not write: http://webwash.net/articles/getting-started-json-drupal-7

Comment: I ended up doing just that. I was able to take a code sample from here and retrofit it. https://api.drupal.org/comment/50023#comment-50023

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing just that. I was able to take a code sample from here and retrofit it. http://api.drupal.org/comment/50023#comment-50023

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
<?php
function configurator_menu() {
    $menu['api/configurator'] = array(
      'title'                   => t('Configurator JSON'),
      'page callback'   => array('configurator_api'),
      'access callback' => true
    );

    return $menu;
}

function taxonomy_get_nested_tree($vid_or_terms = array(), $max_depth = NULL, $parent = 0, $parents_index = array(), $depth = 0) {
  if (!is_array($vid_or_terms)) {
    $vid_or_terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid_or_terms, 0, NULL, TRUE);
  }
  foreach ($vid_or_terms as $term) {
    foreach ($term->parents as $term_parent) {
      if ($term_parent == $parent) {
        $return[$term->tid] = $term;
      } else {
        $parents_index[$term_parent][$term->tid] = $term;
      }
    }
  }
  foreach ($return as &$term) {
    if (isset($parents_index[$term->tid]) && (is_null($max_depth) || $depth < $max_depth)) {
      $term->children = taxonomy_get_nested_tree($parents_index[$term->tid], $max_depth, $term->tid, $parents_index, $depth + 1);
    }
  }
  return 

$return;
}

function taxonomy_nested_tree_render($tree, $recurring = FALSE) {
  $items = array();
  if (count($tree)) {
    foreach ($tree as $term) {

            $image = file_create_url($term->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);
      $item = array('name' => t($term->name), 'image' => t($image));

      if (isset($term->children)) {
        $item["children"] = taxonomy_nested_tree_render($term->children, TRUE);
      }

      $items[] = $item;
    }
  }

  if ($recurring) {
    return $items;
  }

  return $items;
}

function configurator_api() {
    $tree = taxonomy_get_nested_tree(1);
    $items = taxonomy_nested_tree_render($tree);

    print drupal_json_output($items);
    drupal_exit();
}
```